# How can I define an array without a key within another array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

The title sounds a bit confusing, although I'm sure there's a simple solution. I'm using json_encode and am working on a web API. The web API will echo an array that is json_encoded. I want it to look like this:

```
{
    {
        "id": "test",
        "reason": "test reason"
    },
    {
        {
        "id": "test2",
        "reason": "test reason2"
    }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
$array = array();

$array[""] = array();
$array[""]["id"] = "test";
$array[""]["reason"] = "test reason";

$array[""] = array();
$array[""]["id"] = "test";
$array[""]["reason"] = "test reason";
```

This still has a key though ("") which is annoying. I don't want a key. How can I fix this? Thanks! :)

Comment: You can use `array(array("id" => "test", "reason" => "test reason"), array("id" => "test2", "reason" => "test reason2"))` and use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` during `json_encode` to force othe outer part being an object instead of an array (`[...]`).

Comment: Use like `array_push($array,  array('id' => 'test',  'reason'  => 'test reason' ) ) ` then `json_encode($array)` or  `array(array('your data'))`. See if it helps you!

Comment: @ccKep Maybe, although the issue arises when I want to use code to define an array within the array. I don't want to define the array with everything already inside.

Comment: Thanks, @elumalai_kp. Going to try that :)

Comment: @elumalai_kp Yep, your method worked perfectly.

Comment: Cheers..! If worked please accept answer also.

Comment: A PHP array will be encoded as a JSON array ([], no keys), iff all keys a numeric and start from 0, and the keys don't skip any number (careful with deletion), and the internal array order matches the order of the keys (careful when sorting). Many of the suggestions in the comments/answers create such an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is more in line with your original code, you nearly had it nailed

```
<?php
$array = array();

// create 1st detail entry
$arrayDetail = array();
$arrayDetail["id"] = "test";
$arrayDetail["reason"] = "test reason";

$array[] = $arrayDetail; // add detail to array

// create 2nd detail entry
$arrayDetail = array();
$arrayDetail["id"] = "test";
$arrayDetail["reason"] = "test reason";

$array[] = $arrayDetail; // add detail to array

// show the output
var_dump(json_encode($array, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    {
        "id": "test",
        "reason": "test reason"
    },
    {
        {
        "id": "test2",
        "reason": "test reason2"
    }
}
```

This cannot be done for good reason : in javascript, the curly brackets indicate an **object**. Within an object, each property must have a key. The brackets on the other end indicate a numerically-indexed **Array**.

The **Array** type in php may be confusing because it's an all-in-one array, you can mix and match the keys as you see fit.

So this, instead, is valid JSON and might be what you really need (if you don't care about the keys, you'll need to loop over the values):

```
[
    {
        "id": "test",
        "reason": "test reason"
    },
    {
        {
        "id": "test2",
        "reason": "test reason2"
    }
]
```

---

**EDIT**

You may create such an array in php through `json_encode()` like this :

```
$array = [["id"=> "test","reason"=> "test reason"],["id"=> "test","reason"=> "test reason"]];
echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: How could I use this, then? What would the code be to create an array such as the one you posted?

Answer (score 0):

You may get such format as below with `array_push` method,

```
$array = array();
array_push($array, array('id' => 'test', 'reason' => 'test reason' ) );
echo json_encode($array);
```

The resut will be a valid json format as

```
[{"id":"test","reason":"test reason"}]
```